# Using Reactjs to show Json response data on each form submission

Tags: reactjs

How can I use **Reactjs** list records response on each form submission.

I have searched for previous post on this on stackoverflow but most solution I found does not address my issue.

The code below works but only list one record or
replace already existing displayed data on each form submission.

**Here is what I want to achieve.**
If I submit form 4 times am supposed to have 4 records displayed
For Instance

```
uid filename

1   macofile

2   johnfile

3   lukefile

4   tonyfile
```

But what this code does is to replace already existing record on each form submission and 
as a result, it only show just one records

Eg. on 4th form submission it shows only

```
4   tonyfile
```

In **angularjs** I use something like push function to actualize my goal as per code below

```
$scope.users.push(res.data[0]);
```

In **reactjs** if I try the code below

```
const users = users.push(res.data);
//const users = users.push(res.data[0]);
```

it will show error 
**Cannot read property 'push' of undefined**

Here is the code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios, { post } from "axios";

class FilePage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: "",
      filename: "",
      loading: false,
      users: [],
      error: null
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  _handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //send it as form data
    const formData = new FormData();

    formData.append("filename", this.state.filename);

    //alert(this.state.filename);

    this.setState({ loading: true }, () => {
      axios
        .post("http://localhost/apidb_react/up.php", formData)
        .then(res => {

//const users = res.data;
//const users = users.push(res.data[0]);
const users = users.push(res.data);

        this.setState({ users,  loading: false });
/*
          this.setState({
            users: res.data,
            loading: false
          });
*/
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err.message);
        });
    });
  }

  // handle form submission
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    const { loading, users, error } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={e => this._handleSubmit(e)}>
          <b>filename:</b>
          <input
            tyle="text"
            className="form-control"
            value={this.state.filename}
            name="filename"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />

          <button
            className="submitButton"
            type="submit"
            onClick={e => this._handleSubmit(e)}
          >
            submit
          </button>
        </form>




<ul>
    {this.state.users.map((user, index) =>

         <option  key={user.uid}  value='{ user.uid }' > { user.uid } { user.filename}</option>  
 )}

      </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you intended to use `this.state.users.push(...)`

Comment: @Shawn, if I use const users=this.state.users.push(res.data); it shows error. TypeError: this.state.users.map is not a function
    at FilePage.render

Comment: In that case, before the line that creates the error, perform a `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state))` because one of your previous setState(...) calls changed the shape of `users` such that its not an array anymore and therefore couldn't use the map function on a non-array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what works for me is the concat functions as per code below

```
  const users=this.state.users.concat(res.data);
   // const users=this.state.users.push(res.data);// does not work.
```

Consequently, **push()** does not work because it  returns the length of the extended array, instead of the array itself.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

because the local `user` is not defined as an array to have `.push()` function.

`const users=this.state.users;

   users.push(res.data)` then you can replace it with the users in the state.

Comment: if I use const users=this.state.users.push(res.data); it shows error. TypeError: this.state.users.map is not a function
    at FilePage.render

Comment: This is not what I have written in answer, read it more carefully

Comment: Hi Sir, push() does not work because it returns the length of the extended array, instead of the array itself. Concat method works for me. Btw Thanks

Comment: `concat` returns a new list while `push` modifies the existing one. So, the answer given would also work for you, if you were doing that in two different statements as is given in the answer.